# How to refactor my php methods?

Tags: php, refactoring, domdocument

I have a question regarding simplify my codes.

I have

```
 public function getText($text){
      if(!empty($text)){
          $dom = new DomDocument();
          $dom->loadHTML($text);

          $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
          $result = $xpath->query('//a');

          if($result->length > 0){
              $atags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
              foreach($atags as $atag){
                  $style = $atag ->getAttribute('style');
                  $atag->setAttribute('style',$style.' text-decoration:none;color:black;');
              }
              $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
              return $returnText;
          }

          $result = $xpath->query('//table');
          if($result->length > 0){
              $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');              
              $inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

              foreach ($inputs as $input) {
                  $input->setAttribute('style','text-align:center;');
              }

              foreach ($tables as $table) {
                  $table->setAttribute('width',500);
                  $table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed;');
              }
              $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
              return $returnText;
          }
      }
      return $text;
  }

  public function getTextwithIndex($text,$index=''){
      if(!empty($text[$index])){
          $dom = new DomDocument();
          $dom->loadHTML($text[$index]);

          $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
          $result = $xpath->query('//a');

          if($result->length > 0){
              $atags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
              foreach($atags as $atag){
                  $style = $atag ->getAttribute('style');
                  $atag->setAttribute('style',$style.' text-decoration:none;color:black;');
              }
              $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
              return $returnText;
          }

          $result = $xpath->query('//tbody');
          if($result->length > 0){
              $tbodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');
              $cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
              $inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

              foreach ($inputs as $input) {
                  $input->setAttribute('style','text-align:center;');
              }

              foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                  $cell->setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;');
              }

              foreach ($tbodies as $tbody) {
                  $table = $dom->createElement('table');
                  $table->setAttribute('width',500);
                  $table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed;');

                  $tbody->parentNode->replaceChild($table, $tbody);
                  $table->appendChild($tbody);
              }
              $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
              return $returnText;
          }
      }
      return $text;
  }
```

The difference between the method is $index and some modification of my domdocument. I feel like it's really cumbersome and could use some refactoring. Does anyone have any good suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does this actually work? It appears that in both function, if it finds any `<a>` tags it will not process the `<table>` or `<input>` tags at all. Did you mean, CAN YOU DEBUG THIS CODE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public function getTextwithIndex($text,$index='') {
    if (empty($index))
        return getText($text); //not sure how $text works, so this line might be different.

    return getText($text[$index]);
}
```

Or something like this:

```
public function getText($text, $index = false){
    if ($index)
        $text = $text[$index];
  if(!empty($text)){
      $dom = new DomDocument();
      $dom->loadHTML($text);

      $xpath=new DOMXpath($dom);
      $result = $xpath->query('//a');

      if($result->length > 0){
          $atags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
          foreach($atags as $atag){
              $style = $atag ->getAttribute('style');
              $atag->setAttribute('style',$style.' text-decoration:none;color:black;');
          }
          $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
          return $returnText;
      }

      $result = $xpath->query('//table');
      if($result->length > 0){
          if ($index) {
              //do 'getTextWithIndex' dom stuff
          } else {
              $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');              
              $inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
          }

          foreach ($inputs as $input) {
              $input->setAttribute('style','text-align:center;');
          }

          foreach ($tables as $table) {
              $table->setAttribute('width',500);
              $table->setAttribute('style','border:2px solid #8C8C8C;text-align:center;table-layout:fixed;');
          }
          $returnText .= $dom->saveHTML();
          return $returnText;
      }
  }
  return $text;
```

}